# How to round decimal points of legend values in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following plot:

[image]

I would like to round the decimal points of legend values such as the second one (0.999999999534339).

The script that I have written is:

```
ggplot(df) +  
    geom_bar(aes(factor(Run), Freq, fill = factor(Var1), colour = factor(Var1)), position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
    scale_fill_discrete(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1))
```

Note that I added `scale_fill_discrete(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1))` since `scale_fill_discrete` is used to modify the text of the legend and the `labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1)` is used to round the decimal points, but this results in the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("round_any") : 
  no applicable method for 'round_any' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please include the data in your question so that people can reproduce your tries and try to help you solve the problem.

Comment: If you use `labels`, you need to provide a vector of labels. `unique(scales::percent_format(df$Var1, accuracy = 1))` should work, but I don't have a way to check.

Comment: Your variable is `factor`. You probably need to convert it to convert it to `numeric` then use `round` before using it as `factor`